# URL hash doesn't always get removed after popup closes (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, mobile, hash, popup

I'm having a problem where the URL hash, #&ui-state=dialog, doesn't always get removed from the URL after the popup closes. This seems to cause a problem where if I open the popup again and then close it, immediately after closing it, the page content reloads, which messes up the page layout, since it does an ajax refresh and some page layout things are determined in $(document).ready() (I know I'm not supposed to use .ready() for jQuery Mobile, but it works for me for the purposes of this page).

There's no consistency as to how many times I open/close the popup for the URL hash to still remain. But it usually happens at around the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th open/close.

I'm guessing the reload is happening because when a popup is closed it does something to go "back", but if the starting and ending URL are the same then it messes up? I'm almost 100% sure the hash is the problem because I tried visiting my page with the #&ui-state=dialog hash manually put in, and then when I open and close the popup, the page refreshes the first time that I open/close it.

Comment: I think I got it to remove the hash every time, I added `parent.location.hash = ''; history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);` to the function that's called when the popup closes. However, it causes the page to jump to the top, which is undesirable. Is there any way to avoid that?